# Referencing Cells in Excel Web Power Query

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, powerquery

I'm trying to create an excel file which will automatically fetch data from this website 
  (https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTSTK&symbol=SBIN&date=31JAN2019)

where I can change the symbol based on excel cell value. Though I don't able to create it in from power query. I tried VBA macro but first attempt it works but later on it shows error due to the existing table. Here is the VBA code which I have done.

```
Sub OptionChain()
'
' OptionChain Macro
'
TICKER = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Cells.Clear
'
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTSTK&symbol=" & TICKER & "&date=31JAN2019""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(8) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""CALLS OI"", type text}, {""CALLS Chng in OI"", type" & _
    " text}, {""CALLS Volume"", type text}, {""CALLS IV"", type text}, {""CALLS LTP"", type text}, {""CALLS Net Chng"", type text}, {""CALLS Bid Qty"", type text}, {""CALLS Bid Price"", type text}, {""CALLS Ask Price"", type text}, {""CALLS Ask Qty"", type text}, {""Strike Price"", type number}, {""PUTS Bid Qty"", type text}, {""PUTS Bid Price"", type text}, {""PUTS Ask " & _
    "Price"", type text}, {""PUTS Ask Qty"", type text}, {""PUTS Net Chng"", type text}, {""PUTS LTP"", type text}, {""PUTS IV"", type text}, {""PUTS Volume"", type text}, {""PUTS Chng in OI"", type text}, {""PUTS OI"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""


With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 0"";Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 0]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_0"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Can anyone please help me how can I create the web power query from cell paramerters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a little housekeeping and not having the charts you can use xmlhttp

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet, shp As Shape, wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("symbols")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    ws.Cells.Clear
    ws.Cells.UnMerge

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTSTK&symbol=" & wsSource.Cells(1, 1) & "&date=31JAN2019", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = sResponse

    clipboard.SetText html.querySelectorAll("table").Item(2).outerHTML
    clipboard.PutInClipboard
    ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    ClearCharts ws
End Sub
```

---

A long winded way would be:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub WriteOutTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, ws As Worksheet, wsSource As Worksheet, hTable As HTMLTable
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("symbols")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Cells.Clear
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTSTK&symbol=" & wsSource.Cells(1, 1) & "&date=31JAN2019", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = sResponse
    Set hTable = html.querySelector("#octable")

    Dim tr As Object, td As Object, i As Long, th As Object, r As Long, c As Long, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr").Length
    For Each tr In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        r = r + 1: c = 1
        Select Case r
        Case 1
            ws.Cells(r, 1) = tr.getElementsByTagName("th")(0).innerText
            ws.Cells(r, 12) = tr.getElementsByTagName("th")(2).innerText
        Case 2
            For Each th In tr.getElementsByTagName("th")
                If Not th.title = "Chart" Then
                    c = c + 1
                    ws.Cells(r, c) = th.title
                End If
            Next
        Case lastRow
            ws.Cells(r, 1) = "Total"
            ws.Cells(r, 2) = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText
            ws.Cells(r, 3) = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")(3).innerText
            ws.Cells(r, 19) = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")(5).innerText
            ws.Cells(r, 21) = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")(7).innerText
        Case Else
            c = 2
            For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                If td.classname = "ylwbg" Or td.classname = "nobg" Or td.classname = "grybg" Then
                    ws.Cells(r, c) = td.innerText
                    c = c + 1
                End If
            Next
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a cell value using Power Query, by defining a named range.

So your query may look something like:

```
let
    Symbol = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MySymbol"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    Date = Text.Upper(DateTime.ToText(DateTime.LocalNow(),"ddMMMyyyy")),
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTSTK&symbol=" & Symbol & "&date=" & Date)),
    Data = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Change Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Data), each {_, type number})),
    #"Replace Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Change Type", List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Change Type"), each {_, null}))
in
    #"Replace Errors"
```

Now you can change the Symbol in cell "MySymbol" and simply refresh the query.